# Scrapy Redis: fetch next_request without waiting for idle signal

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy framework to make api calls (broad crawls) and using scrapy redis for running it in the distributed network.  I am fetching the start urls from Redis and then using middleware to make the subsequent request. The response time of the task (initial request + set of subsequent requests) varies with reference to the API parameters.

Since spiders in `scrapy-redis` rely on the spider idle signal to fetch start urls. I am unable to utilize all the resources as it waits for the batch request to be over ( batch size = 100 ).

How can I tweak the `scrapy-redis`, so it immediately fetches the start urls after the task is over. I tried running multiple processes with `redis-batch-size=1`, but it didn't solve my problem as each scrapy process takes a lot of memory.